# хочу сделать так чтобы программа возвращалась на на выбор

Tags: python

```
print('***** |1|вы можете осмотреться или |2|выйти на палобу')
 z=int(input())
  if z==1:
    print('вы осмотрели свою каюту')
    print('это была не большая комнатка')
    print('обделанная асилским дубом, что придавало темно синий цвет')
    print('так же у стены стоит сундук с одеждой')
    print('вытоге вы вышли на палубу')

  if z==2:

   print('qwqw')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    print('***** |1|вы можете осмотреться или |2|прыгнуть в море')
    z = int(input())
    if z == 1:
        print('вы осмотрели свою каюту')
        print('это была не большая комнатка')
        print('обделанная асилским дубом, что придавало темно синий цвет')
        print('так же у стены стоит сундук с одеждой')
        print('вытоге вы вышли на палубу')
        print()
        continue

    if z == 2:
        print('Жалкие останки бреного тела')
        print("были поедены сверепыми акулами")
        print('смеркалось...')
        break
```